# Is this a bad practice?

Tags: java

Is the following code considered a bad practice? Do you think it can be done otherwise?
The goal is to always update the status, either with success  (i.e invocation to service.invoke(id);returns normally ) or with failure...

```
@Autowired
private Service service;

public void onMessage(Message message) {

    String id = null;
    String status = "FAILED";

    try {
        id = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
        status = service.invoke(id); //can throw unchecked exception
    } catch (final JMSException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(id)) {
        service.update(id, status);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put that `default` update code, in your `catch` and once done, throw your exception. Avoid the `finally` clause.

Comment: @JustinYang what do you mean exactly? The `finally` will be called _after_ the `try`. What do you mean by "swallow"?

Comment: @bmorris591 is right. The `throw` will still happen after the `finally` block is executed. It would be swallowed if the `finally` also threw an exception.

Comment: @JustinYang Can you elaborate?

Comment: The way you have it now, even if the `register` is successful, you will still do the default behavior. Is this what you want?

Comment: @JustinYang you are mistaken my friend. `finally` is just used to execute the code in-any-case whether try-catch blocks execute normally or not, even if return statements or exceptions are thrown in try-catch blocks, finally block has to execute, and return the control, as if there was no finally block

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, if the register() is success i will get back a status = "SUCESS" and i will use that to update, otherwise the default failed will be used...

Comment: @boom123 I don't know if I was clear enough. The code in the `finally` block will be executed whether or not your register was successful. It might override a change you've already done, so be careful.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, this is clear. i want the update() to happen regardless of what happened in the register. The problem is that i dont like the initialization of the status to failed, that is what i am asking if it can be done otherwise...

Comment: there is nothing wrong with initializing the status to failed, if that's your question. That's how you should do it.

Comment: You could also update the subject as to what exactly you think in this code is bad practice.

Comment: How does your transaction management work? Does is roll back on `RuntimeException` (EJB and Spring do per default)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Use-case, whether you have to perform a step or not based on previous step. Using finally may execute your second step regardless what exception you may receive.

I would recommend having the second step outside `try...catch` block so that you'll update only when you have got any exception you've Expected and continue to your second step, else, your method will throw and exit.

Comment: I updated my code, invocation to service.register(id); can throw an uncheked exception, that i want to propagate and rollback the trascaction. But i still require to update that failure...

Comment: Given that his catch throws an exception, the code after the catch will never be seen unless it's in a finally.

Comment: You can wrap `service.register(id);` in a `try...catch` where you're catching the exception, you ARE expecting. Unchecked is just that your compiler won't ask you to handle it so your `catch` can get it. Only, `Error` can't be handled by `catch`.  In that case, `finally` won't help you as it'll thrash your thread. Record that status and throw exception if you want the caller to know the status. The reason, I suggest this way is that you can have multiple steps after the failure, which you don't have to place inside finally.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should not use  implementation of message listener , you should wire them independent of spring tech . just pojo based . use  `<jms:listener-container >`  with `<jms:listener>`

Comment: can you give further explanations as to why you think spring autowiring is bad?

Comment: i am not taking about auto wiring . i am taking about "MessageListener"

Comment: Spring in action ch 13  page 326